# Undo move files from the "all my files" to the trash folder

Tags: finder, trash

I transferred by mistake  some files from the "all my files" folder to the trash folder (but haven't emptied it). Do I risk to delete these files? How can I undo this?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I risk to delete these files?

You're fine as long as you don't empty the Trash.

> How can I undo this?

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> will undo the last action in Finder. So if you just deleted them you can use this shortcut to undelete them all.

Otherwise:

1. Click on the Trash icon in your Dock to open the Trash view in Finder
2. For each file in the Trash, right click on the file and select `Put Back` from the menu (unfortunately you can't issue the "put back" instruction to multiple files at once, [see this answer for a way to do it in groups of files that might work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38206/292) or [this one if you're comfortable running some AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115476/292))